# C#: marshalling a struct that contains arrays

Tags: c#, interop, marshalling

I am doing some C# interop work. I have the following struct:

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
typedef struct
{
    unsigned __int64 Handle;
    LinkType_t Type;
    LinkState_t State;
    unsigned __int64 Settings;
    signed __int8 Name[MAX_LINK_NAME];
    unsigned __int8 DeviceInfo[MAX_LINK_DEVINFO];
    unsigned __int8 Reserved[40];
} LinkInfo_t;
```

This is my attempt to convert it into a C# struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct LinkInfo_t
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)]
    public UInt64 Handle;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public LinkType_t Type;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public LinkState_t State;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U8)]
    public UInt64 Settings;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = MAX_LINK_NAME)]
    public string Name;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAX_LINK_DEVINFO, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public byte[] DeviceInfo;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 40, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1)]
    public byte[] Reserved;
}
```

However, whenever I initialize the struct the `Name`, `DeviceInfo`, and `Reserved` fields are all set to null. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the arrays, try to use the `fixed` keyword:

```
public fixed byte DeviceInfo[MAX_LINK_DEVINFO];
public fixed byte Reserved[40];
```

Comment: This works for the arrays. However the correct syntax is
public fixed byte DeviceInfo[MAX_LINK_DEVINFO];

I also have to declare the struct as unsafe.

Comment: So I looked in to this -- if I do this, I have to turn on `unsafe` code. I know this was answered over 11 years ago, so maybe things have changed since then.

Answer (score 4):

> whenever I initialize the struct the
>   Name, DeviceInfo, and Reserved fields
>   are all set to null

This is correct, and your definition looks OK to me (BTW, you don't need `[MarshalAs]` on the primitive fields, the default behaviour is to do what you specified there). Because your array fields are `null`, the marshaler won't do anything about them when marshaling your struct to unmanaged memory, but it's going to create the strings and arrays when unmarshaling.

Comment: instead of unsafe and fixed, the code should allocate the byte arrays before using it.  I normally have a constructor on structs for p/invoke where any arrays are automatically allocated.

Answer (score 3):

What Anton Tykhyy says is correct. I just want to clarify with some examples. Using 'fixed' works, but that forces you to use 'unsafe' as well. I like to avoid using unsafe wherever possible. Using Marshal is a way to get around that.

First, let's say that I have a library that was created in C with the following definitions.

```
typedef struct {
    int messageType;
    BYTE payload[60];
} my_message;

/**
* \param[out] msg    Where the message will be written to
*/
void receiveMessage(my_message *msg);

/*
* \param[in] msg    The message that will be sent
*/
void sendMessage(my_message *msg);
```

In C#, the following structure would be equivalent to the one in C.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 64), Serializable]
struct my_message
{
    int messageType;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray,SizeConst = 60)]
    byte[] payload;

    public initializeArray()
    {
        //explicitly initialize the array
        payload = new byte[60];
    }
}
```

Since the msg in receiveMessage() is documented as [out], you don't need to do anything special to the array in the structure before passing it to the function. i.e.:

```
my_message msg = new my_message();
receiveMessage(ref msg);
byte payload10 = msg.payload[10];
```

Since the msg in sendMessage() is documented as [in], you will need to fill the array before calling the function. Before filling the array, the array needs to be explicitly instantiated before using it. i.e.:

```
my_message msg = new my_message();
msg.initializeArray();
msg.payload[10] = 255;
sendMessage(ref msg);
```

Calling initializeArray() should instantiate the array in the previously allocated space created within the struct for this array.