# Call a method through Interop which returns an instance of a struct

Tags: c#, c++, .net, interop

I'm new to Interop and need to call a managed C++ method from C# which returns an instance of the following `struct`:

```cpp
typedef struct DataBlock_ {
  unsigned char data[10240];
  unsigned int numberOfBytes;
  unsigned long int startAddr;    
} DataBlock;
```

The C++ method which returns the instance is declared as follows:

```cpp
__declspec(dllexport) DataBlock getDefaultPass( void ) 
{
    DataBlock default_pass = {
        {
            (char)0xFF,(char)0xFF,(char)0xFF,(char)0xFF,
            (char)0xFF,(char)0xFF,(char)0xFF,(char)0xFF,
            (char)0xFF,(char)0xFF,(char)0xFF,(char)0xFF,
            (char)0xFF,(char)0xFF,(char)0xFF,(char)0xFF,
            (char)0xFF,(char)0xFF,(char)0xFF,(char)0xFF,
            (char)0xFF,(char)0xFF,(char)0xFF,(char)0xFF,
            (char)0xFF,(char)0xFF,(char)0xFF,(char)0xFF,
            (char)0xFF,(char)0xFF,(char)0xFF,(char)0xFF
        },
        32,
        0xFFE0
    };
    return default_pass;
}
```

I've declared the struct and method in C# as follows:

```
public static partial class My
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DataBlock
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10240)]
        public byte[] data;
        //public fixed byte data[10240]; <-- this requires 'unsafe' but still doesn't work      
        public UInt32 numberOfBytes;
        public UInt32 startAddr;
    }

    [DllImport("my.dll")]
    static public extern DataBlock getDefaultPass( );

    [DllImport("my.dll")]
    static public extern byte sendPassword(DataBlock data);
}
```

I call the method from C# as follows:

```
var defaultPassword = My.getDefaultPass();
var response = My.sendPassword(defaultPassword);
```

but the call to `getDefaultPass()` throws

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException' occurred in
>   ConsoleApplication1.exe
>
> Additional information: Method's type signature is not PInvoke
>   compatible.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455034/c-marshalling-a-struct-that-contains-arrays), I tried changing the declaration of `data` to `public fixed byte data[10240]` and marked the struct as `unsafe`, but then the method returns an instance with `numberOfBytes` and `startAddr` set to 0, and the subsequent call to `sendPassword()` fails (note that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22732641/399576) the subsequent calls use a pointer to the struct as opposed to the instance itself, as is my case). How then should I be calling the method(s) from C#?

The project targets .NET 3.5 and x86.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: @MatthewWatson No, the struct is actually blittable. While returning large structures like this is tricky, blittability is not the problem.

Comment: Are you using GCC to compile the native code? If so, it's very likely that it's emitting the function to actually take a `ref` argument rather than returning the struct. The real signature would then be something like `static public extern void getDefaultPass(out DataBlock data)`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7(v=vs.110).aspx. `byte` is blittable. Fixed-size arrays of blittable types are themselves blittable. Thus, `byte[]` (as defined by the OP) is blittable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15664100/17034

Comment: @Luaan I'm being told it's compiled in Visual Studio as well (I don't maintain it, nor do I think I could change it). Does that help or would you need more specifics about build/link configuration?

Comment: @MatthewWatson `char` != `byte` in the C# world. `byte` is blittable. `char` is not. In this case, the OP wants `byte`, not `char`, which is fine.

Comment: @Luaan Ahh I misread the array as being chars (since I was looking at the C++ struct definition, which uses `unsigned char` instead of `byte`).

Comment: Well, first you should make sure the calling conventions are in order, as explained in Hans' comment - the name may be mangled, and the C++ code might be using a different calling convention than the default StdCall; the C++ guys should be able to answer this for you easily. If that doesn't help, try the `out` trick.

Comment: @Luaan Brilliant! The `out` trick worked! The calling convention is `__cdecl (/Gd)`. Cheers

Comment: @Luaan PS: feel free to include that as an answer, unless it's already been linked and I missed it (?)

Comment: Yeah, you really want to use `[DllImport("my.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]` as well if you're using CDecl.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, adding the `CallingConvention` to the method's declaration in C# still failed. Only changing the method to take an `out` parameter worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `struct` is fine - it fulfills all the rules to be used as a return value in P/Invoke.

You need to use the proper calling convention (in your case, `CallingConvention.Cdecl`).

There's also an extra optimization that some compilers use, where a big structure (such as yours) is passed by reference, rather than returned. You can replicate this in C# like so:

```
static public extern void getDefaultPass(out DataBlock data);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness and to complement Luaan's answer, since the C++ method in the question has no parameters, I wanted to cover the case where a method did have parameters, specifically as it relates to the position of the `out` parameter when the method takes 2 or more arguments.

Consider the C++ method

```
__declspec(dllexport) DataBlock readText(char * dataArray , int bytesToRead)
```

It's not immediately obvious whether the `out` parameter should be first or last in the C# method. Contrary to the framework's convention of placing the `out` parameter as the last parameter (e.g. `TryParse`), here it must be the **first** parameter, otherwise the call will fail:

```
[DllImport("my.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static public extern void readText(out DataBlock dataBlock, string dataArray, int bytesToRead);
```